# How to disable action in background of fancybox window

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, modal-dialog

http://www.monmouthchineseschool.com/
if you click on 'Staff' under 'Information' a fancybox window will open up. Here is the jQuery code for it.

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox({
      'hideOnContentClick' : false
    });
    jQuery("a.fancy_iframe").fancybox({
      'width' : '95%',
      'height' : '95%',
      'autoScale' : false,
      'type' : 'iframe',
      'centerOnScroll' : true,
      'onStart' : function() {
        $("body").css({'overflow':'hidden'});
      },
      'onClosed' : function() {
        $("body").css({"overflow":"visible"});
      }
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

The `overflow:hidden` removes the scroll bar in the main window, but then if you click on 'Mandarin', it will still move the background page.

Also on a separate note, how would I 'transfer' the scrollbar from the modal box to the parent window, similar to Facebook's new theater mode.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `$("..")` inside `jQuery('...')` block. Have you try to change like this?

```
 jQuery("body").css({'overflow':'hidden'});
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer and should probably be a comment unless you are sure it is an answer.